# Font-size on parents not changing the p children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I read about the CSS cascading rules and fully aware with that.

- Inline styling : 1000 pts
- ID             : 100 pts
- Class          : 10 pts
- Element        : 1 pts

But it turned out something weird happens with my code. When I am having higher specificity points, the style does not apply.

Here I am trying to replicate the problem:

```css
p {
  font-size: 10px
}


div.container {
  font-size: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="font-size:20px;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga nesciunt voluptatum eligendi tempora odio nemo delectus adipisci fugiat quasi quam hic pariatur ea beatae voluptas quae quas, blanditiis incidunt quia.</p>
</div>
```

The p tag don't follow the font-size I set inline and even on the css files. Even when it is much lower in terms of position and higher in terms of specificity points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that this is not a specificity points problem but more to inheritance and cascading I think. Glad I learned something now.

The problem is, setting the font-size to the parents is actually will only be used when the font-size is not set on the target children itself. When it is not set, it will cascade up to the parents until it founds the property of font-size

But when it is set anywhere even much earlier in terms of position(low priority) or with lower specificity points, it won't cascade up to look up for the font-size property.

```css
p {
  font-size: 10px
}


div.container {
  font-size: 30px !important;
}

.container p {
  font-size: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container" style="font-size:20px;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga nesciunt voluptatum eligendi tempora odio nemo delectus adipisci fugiat quasi quam hic pariatur ea beatae voluptas quae quas, blanditiis incidunt quia.</p>
</div>
```

This one works because I explicitly set the `font-size` attributes on the `p` tag inside the `div.container` itself overriding the earlier styling I set for the `p` tags

Note that, if I remove the styling for p tag earlier, it will take the `font-size` of the parents

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.container {
  font-size: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="font-size:20px;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga nesciunt voluptatum eligendi tempora odio nemo delectus adipisci fugiat quasi quam hic pariatur ea beatae voluptas quae quas, blanditiis incidunt quia.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet I provide above is not the real instance of the problem. I replicate it with much simpler approach. So, I can't easily remove the styling for p tag as it will affects stylings on other pages. I figured out why it happens.

Comment: <p> tag follow inline css. First inner tag get priority than after parent css apply

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
div.container p{
   font-size: 30px; 
}
```

Comment: This will works even without the `!important`. I figured out the causes in my answer.

Comment: it will work, for some safty reason using `!important`

Comment: I don't think using !important is a good practice. It should be avoided as much as possible.